# when will /proc/<pid> be removed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Process A opened && mmaped thousand of files when running. Then `killl -9 <pid of process A>` is issued. Then I have a question about the sequence of below two events.
a) `/proc/<pid of process A>` cannot be accessed.
b)  all files opened by process A are closed.

More background about the question:
Process A is a multi-thread background service. It is started by cmd `./process_A  args1 arg2 arg3`.
There is also a watchdog process which checked whether process A is still alive periodically(every 1 second). If process A is dead, then restart it. The way watchdog checks process A is as below.
1) collect all numerical subdir under `/proc/`
2) compares `/proc/<all-pids>/cmdline` with cmdline of process A. If these is a `/proc/<some-pid>/cmdline` matches, then process A is alive and do nothing, otherwise restart process A.

process A will do below stuff when doing initialization.
1) open fileA
2) flock fileA
3) mmap fileA into memory
4) close fileA
process A will mmap thousand of files after initialization.
after several minutes, `kill -9 <pid of process A>` is issued. 
watchdog detect the death of process A, restart it. But sometimes process A stuck at `step 2 flock fileA`. After some debugging, we found that unlock of fileA is executed when process A is killed. But sometimes this event will happen after `step 2 flock fileA` of new process.
So we guess the way to check process alive by monitor `/proc/<pid of process A>`
is not correct.

Comment: Can you share with us the reason why you're asking this question?  If the answer is that (1) happens before (2), what will you do?  If it's the other way around, what will you do?  If it's indeterminate, what will you do?

Comment: @JohnZwinck  added more background

Comment: What is your process A actually doing? What happens when it is crashing? Do you then lose data? How? Why? How much?

Comment: I have seen reports that readdir of /proc will sometimes overlook some entries. This might explain what you're seeing. If you must scan through /proc, try doing it twice before concluding that the process has exited. Or, just check for the (non) existence of `/proc/pid/stat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't scan `/proc/PID` to find out if a specific process has terminated.  There are lots of better ways to do that, such as having your watchdog program actually launch the server program and wait for it to terminate.

Or, have the watchdog listen on a TCP socket, and have the server process connect to that and send its PID.  If either end dies, the other can notice the connect was closed (hint: send a heartbeat packet every so often, to a frozen peer).  If the watchdog receives a connection from another server while the first is still running, it can decide to allow it or tell one of the instances to shut down (via TCP or `kill()`).

Comment: While this is a useful workaround, it does not answer the question. Using a socket transforms the original question into: What is the sequence of these events: socket is closed or files opened by the process are closed. But I doubt there will be a definitive answer and would instead expect the answer to be: It depends on the order of the file handles used ...

Answer (score 6):

> then `kill -9`   is issued

This is bad habit. You'll better send a `SIGTERM` first. Because well behaved processes and well designed programs can catch it (and exit *nicely* and *properly* when getting a `SIGTERM`...). In some cases, I even recommend: sending `SIGTERM`. Wait two or three seconds. sending `SIGQUIT`. Wait two seconds. At last, send a `SIGKILL` signal (for those bad programs who have not been written properly or are misbehaving). A few seconds later, you could send a `SIGKILL`. Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). In multi-threaded, but Linux specific, programs, you might use [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) or the [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self trick (well [explained](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) in Qt documentation, but not Qt specific).

If your Linux system is [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) based, you could imagine your *program-A* is started with *systemd* facilities. Then you'll use systemd facilities to "communicate" with it. In some ways (I don't know the details), systemd is making [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) almost obsolete. Notice that signals are not multi-thread friendly and have been designed, in the previous century, for single-thread processes.

> we guess the way to check process alive by monitor /proc/ is not correct.

The usual (and faster, and "atomic" enough) way to detect the existence of a process (on which you have enough privileges, e.g. which runs with your uid/gid) is to use [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) with a signal number (the second argument to `kill`) of 0. To quote that manpage:

```
   If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but existence and permission
   checks are still performed; this can be used to check for the
   existence of a process ID or process group ID that the caller is
   permitted to signal.
```

Of course, that other process can still terminate before any further interaction with it. Because Linux has preemptive scheduling.

You watchdog process should better use `kill(`*pid-of-process-A*`, 0)` to check existence and liveliness of that *process-A*. Using `/proc/`*pid-of-process-A*`/`  is not the correct way for that.

And whatever you code, that *process-A* could disappear asynchronously (in particular, if it has some bug that gives a segmentation fault). When a process terminates (even with a segmentation fault) the *kernel* is acting on its file locks (and "releases" them).

Comment: `kill -9` is used to test our watchdog program

Comment: But as I am explaining, this is bad habit.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But you'd need to test the system can recover from unclean termination of a service and make sure it can start back up in a sane state.

Comment: @IanAbbott: I agree, but believe it is the responsibility of that service, not of the entire system.+

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If services behaved responsibly all the time, a watchdog wouldn't be needed!

Comment: Yes. I am not so sure a watchdog is useful in practice.

Comment: Using `kill -0` transforms the original question into: What is the sequence of these events: `kill -0` fails or all files opened by the process are closed.